# Using Pytest fixture with different inputs in different data rather than same data

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

i have a pytest fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(params=PW.getCases())
def getData(self, request):
    return request.param
```

this returns a series of test data each time, i have a test like

```
            def test_Sample(self, getData):
            for case in range(casecount):
                casePage.caseList1()[case].click()
```

Here the same test executes for all the series of param, but is there a way that i can increment the param for each increment in case?
I have tried using **scope** in fixture but no success

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to excecute the click only once for each test case, or something like this? Can you describe what the params from `getCases` are, and how they relate to `caseList1`? And what do you mean by "increment the param"?

Comment: it actually generates a series of values which i will be using after the click operation. So basically i have a list of cases, which i iterate and click. on clicking each will lead to a different page and i want one set of params for one page, the next set of paraments for the next page and so on.

Comment: So the page and the parameters actually belong together - in this case I would put them together in the params, for example by letting `getCases` return a list of tuples. There would be no need for iteration in the case then.